# Update bitmap on button click

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, buttonclick, redraw

I am drawing a box with certain measurements and updating the angle at which it is viewed which I set as a double 'offset'. I am trying to get the view to change as I click a button to increase its offset. How would I update the bitmap to reflect the button click.

"

```
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myBitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width,
            this.ClientRectangle.Height);

        graphicsObj = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
        Pen linePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
        graphicsObj.Drawline(linePen, 50, 50, 100, 50);

    public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphicsObj = e.Graphics;
        graphicsObj.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
     }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        offsetButton = offsetButton + .10;
        **call or update bitmap**
    }
```

"

Comment: Not clear what you're asking; maybe this can help clarify the *concept*: [How to: Rotate, Reflect, and Skew Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-rotate-reflect-and-skew-images) -- What is the point of this assignment: `Graphics graphicsObj = e.Graphics;`?

Comment: without that I get an error of "Parameter is not vaild on next line, when i DrawImage.       I have edited the orignal post to show how I set my graphicsObj.

Comment: That's because you're trying, for some reason, to store the Graphics object derived from a Bitmap: `graphicsObj = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);` and the use the same object in a different local scope, `Form1_Paint`, where it doesn't belong at all. Just use `e.Graphics.DrawImage(...);` in `Form1_Paint` -- Still not clear what you're asking, though

Comment: I draw the line in Form1_load. Please see the edit.   this is my first experience with bitmap and I was trying to follow a tutorial. I am looking for a good tutorial to explain basic graphics and bitmaps